# How to wait for function in script 1 to finish before starting script 2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I have GameObjectName which has script 1 and script 2 attached to it. Script1 is an IEnumerator like this.

```
public IEnumerator Sunglasses()
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Script2 looks like this.

```
public void Start()
{
    Function1();
    String blah = "Things";
    Function2();
    StartCoroutine(Routine2());
    StartCoroutine(Routine3());
}
```

I need script 1 to finish Sunglasses before script 2 does anything. If I try accessing GameObjectName.Script1 from Script2, Unity says it doesn't exist. How can I make sure that script 1 finishes before starting script 2?

Comment: The only function that is called before `Start()` is `Awake()`, you might need to access whatever you were trying to access in a later function

Comment: You can look into Script Execution Order settings in Unity. It's in Edit>Project Settings> Script Execution Order.

Comment: You should give a better name for the function `Sunglasses` as I have really no idea what it does. Does it `FindSunglasses`, `PaintSunglasses`, `BreakSunglasses`, `MakeSunglasses`, `SellSunglasses`, etc.? (All of those would be much better function names)

Comment: @Ryolu `The only function that is called before Start() is Awake()` thats not true! You can refer to [Event ExecutionOrder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) -> `OnEnable` e.g. is also called before `Start`.

Comment: @derHugo I did not know that(evidently). This seems interestingly useful

Comment: @Jessica what's the status of this question? You've been given comments and answers, yet I don't see any interaction or accepting an answer that best solved the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a boolean variable in script one, after the `Sunglasses` function call is done, set it to `true`.

**Script1:**

```
public bool isDone = false;

public IEnumerator Sunglasses()
{
    // Do stuff

    isDone = true;
}
```

**Script2:**

Then in your Script2, you can make your `Start` function to be a coroutine or `IEnumerator`  instead of a `void` function. After this, you can wait for `isDone` to be true every frame.

```
public bool isDone;
Script1 script1Ref;

public IEnumerator Start()
{
    GameObject s1Obj = GameObject.Find("GameObjectScript1IsAttachedTo");
    script1Ref = s1Obj.GetComponent<Script1>();

    //Wait here until we are done
    while (!script1Ref.isDone)
        yield return null;

    //Done Waiting, now continue with the rest of the code
    Function1();
    String blah = "Things";
    Function2();
    StartCoroutine(Routine2());
    StartCoroutine(Routine3());
}
```

Finally, if you also need to make sure that Script1 is dine before doing something in the `Update` function of Script2, just check the `isDone` variable and return if it it still `false`.

```
void Update()
{
    //Return if script 1 is not done
    if (!script1Ref.isDone)
        return;

    //The rest of your code below


}
```

---

Note that you want `StartCoroutine(Routine3())` to wait until `StartCoroutine(Routine2())` is done, you have to yield it.

Replace `StartCoroutine(Routine3())` with `yield return StartCoroutine(Routine3())`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try studying events, or observer pattern. What I have been using is the latter which allows me to add callbacks with a string identifier. For events, you do something like

```
public static event System.Action onSunglassesCompleted;
public IEnumerator Sunglasses()
{
    //Sunglasses logic here

    //if there is a listener to the event, call it
    if(onSunglassesCompleted != null)
    {
        onSunglassesCompleted();
    }
}
```

Then on Script2, you just have to add the listener to the event

```
void Start()
{
    Script1.onSunglassesCompleted += DoThisAfterSunglasses;
}

//This will be called in Script1
void DoThisAfterSunglasses()
{
    //Make sure you do this to avoid memory leaks or missing reference errors once Sprite1 is destroyed
    Script1.onSunglassesCompleted -= DoThisAfterSunglasses;

    Function1();
    String blah = "Things";
    Function2();
    StartCoroutine(Routine2());
    StartCoroutine(Routine3());
}
```

One thing you can do in events to avoid leaks is by setting it to null after you call it.

```
if(onSunglassesCompleted != null)
{
    onSunglassesCompleted();
    onSunglassesCompleted = null;
}
```

Comment: I'ld prefere to add the listener already in Awake in order to make sure it wasn't already fired by Script1 before the listener was added. Also note that in order to avoid "multible" listening I'ld just add `Script1.onSunglassesCompleted -= DoThisAfterSunglasses;` right before `Script1.onSunglassesCompleted += DoThisAfterSunglasses;`. this works since it is allowed to "remove" a listener that isn't there yet but makes sure there is maximum 1 even if for some reson `Start`/`Awake` is called again by script.

Comment: And I think you should call the event like `onSunglassesCompleted.Invoke();`

Comment: But nevertheless this is the cleanest solution I would have used as well ;)

Comment: Ahh, yes.. Adding it in Awake() would be a safe way to ensure that the event listener is added before it is invoked.